# want to display the images count of one html page in other html page in the same folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get the number of images in page1 to be displayed in page2?

page1:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>     
<head>         
<title>images count</title>         
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>         <script>            
 $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#count").html($(".galery img").length);            
 });          
</script>     
</head>      
<body>        
 <div id="box">            
 <p style="padding: 20px;">Images Count:<span id="count"></span></p>   
</div>        
<div class="galery">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
</div>      
 </body> 
</html>
```

page2:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>   
  <head>       
  <title></title>    
 </head>      
<body>         
Page1 Images count:<span id="newcount"></span>      
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Either you can use localStorage for this or if the pages share the same javascript file then you can just make a global variable in the first file and the second file can directly access it.

Comment: @ Karan Dhir, please provide me with some source code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage for this:

Page 1:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>     
<head>         
<title>images count</title>         
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js></script>         
<script>            
 $(document).ready(function(){
     localStorage.setItem("count", $(".galery img").length);            
 });          
</script>     
</head>      
<body>        
 <div id="box">            
 <p style="padding: 20px;">Images Count:<span id="count"></span></p>   
</div>        
<div class="galery">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
</div>      
 </body> 
</html>
```

In page 2:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>   
  <head>       
  <title></title> 
<script>            
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var count = localStorage.getItem("count");
      $("#count").html(count)      
 });          
</script>    
 </head>      
<body>         
    Page1 Images count:<span id="newcount"></span>      
</body>
</html>
```

So basically, in page 1 you can store some data in localstorage, and in page 2 you can retrieve it from localstorage and display it.

Comment: with out using local storage can it be possible by calling the classes or id of one page to the other.

Comment: No! HTML pages cannot access each other(s DOM).

Comment: @Vinod Bhavnani / JoostS, for the above question only, if my database name is 'test'. how can i write the code, kindly help me out with this

Comment: @Saif writing to a database depends on what backend language you are using and what database you are using. Typically for such a small issue, I wouldn't recommend using a database. Why would you want to use database tables and records just to store number of images. HTML5 localstorage and sessionstorage are just for this reason.To store relativelysmall amount of data on the browser rather that using database. There is a lot of overhead involved for using a database for this.

Comment: Also I see that you are using very old techniques to build your application. I would rather use some MVC or MVVP framework to build single page applications, where you can maintain the state of your application. It's a huge learning curve, but it's much beneficial in many aspects.

Comment: @ Vinod Bhavnani, i had this requirement for my project, below are the complete details for your better understanding.

I have created a database to retrieve the uploaded images.

database name: text table name: ntable

it contains 3 columns, namely ID, File_name, type.

now i want to display the count of total images retrieved in data in other html page. Kindly help me how can i do this.

Comment: @ Vinod Bhavnani, i had this requirement for my project, below are the complete details for your better understanding. I have created a database to retrieve the uploaded images. database name: text table name: ntable it contains 3 columns, namely ID, File_name, type. now i want to display the count of total images retrieved in data in other html page. Kindly help me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

send image count as parameter

Page1

```
<html>     
<head>         
<title>images count</title>         
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>         <script>            
 $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#count").html($(".galery img").length);   

               $(".spage").click(function(){

window.location.href="file:///C:/Users/**/Desktop/page02.html?count="+$(".galery img").length;

})         
 });          
</script>     
</head>      
<body>        
 <div id="box">            
 <p style="padding: 20px;">Images Count:<span id="count"></span></p>   <a class="spage"> second page</a>
</div>        
<div class="galery">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
<img src="download.png">           
</div>  

 </body>
</html>
```

Page2

```
<html>   
  <head>       
  <title></title>    
 </head>      
<body>         
Page1 Images count:<span id="newcount"></span>      
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
var imageCount = $.urlParam('count');  

$("#newcount").html(imageCount)
</script>
</body>


 </html>
```